# Can't use generic type declared at method level for method argument that requires a generic type that's declared somewhere else

Tags: java, generics

My ultimate goal is to have a `StateTransitionTable`, where the client can create an entry which consists of a `mainState` and states it can jump to from that main state (stored in an `ArrayList`). This application, `Script`, runs on a loop, and the transition table should be somewhat self-operating.

**Please do not recommend me using enums for this; they do not scale well**

Each state should have access to both the `Script` and the `TransitionTable` instances. The script is to carry-out it's duty, and the table is to transition to the next state, using an index. The indexes depend on the order the transitions were added to the entry. The first entry created is the first entry used.

In the application's loop, the state stored in the current entry should be accessed, and `process` should be called from it. `Script` calls `<T extends Script> process(T)`, passing in the current script instance:

```
//this method is called repeatedly
public void loop() {
    table.process(this);
}
```

That method grabs the `mainState` from the `currentEntry` and invokes the `process(T, TransitionTable)` method, passing in the `Script` instance and the current table instance. From within the state's process method, I should be able to access information about the script using the `script` parameter, and make my transitions using the table. It seems I have everything in order, except for 1 statement that is giving me an error.

```
public interface State<T extends Script> {
    void process(T script, TransitionTable table);
}
```

TransitionTable:

```
public class TransitionTable {
    private Map<State<?>, StateNode> entries = new HashMap<>();
    private StateNode currentNode, startNode;

    public <T extends Script> void process(T script) {
        currentNode.mainState.process(script, this); //Compile-time error here
    }

    public StateNode createEntry(State<?> state) {
        StateNode node = new StateNode(state);
        map.put(state, node);

        if(startNode == null)
            startNode = currentNode = node;

        return node;
    }

    public void transitionTo(int index) {
        State<?> nextState = currentNode.states.get(index);
        if(nextState == null)
             nextNode = startNode.mainState;

        currentNode = entries.get(nextNode);
    }

    public static final class StateNode {
        private ArrayList<State<?>> states = new ArrayList<>;
        private State<?> mainState;

        public StateNode(State<?> state) {
            mainState = state;
        }

        public StateNode addTransition(State<?> state) {
            states.add(state); 
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

For the record, the generic type declaration for `process` is a cheap hack to allow usages of the actual script's type. Although a different type can be entered, it will always be the same type. Cheap hack.

The error I get is:

> The method process(capture#4-of ?, StateTransitionTable) in the type State is not applicable for the arguments (T, StateTransitionTable)

I understand the reasoning behind this: There's a chance the client will specify a subtype for the method's type parameter that differs from `State`'s type parameter. What I don't understand is how I'm supposed to counter-act a situation like this.

I know there's a tag for design problems like this, but I don't remember it's name. If someone could add that in, it would be appreciated. If you feel I've left out any relevant info, please let me know

Comment: Not what you asked, but have you considered using the State pattern from GoF?

Comment: @EricStein This is actually very similar to the state pattern, except it has the added complexity of specifying states to jump to. I can't easily change the state using something like `table.changeState(state)`since I don't have a reference to the state I want to change to. That's why I have the `transitionTo` method accepts an index , and I allow the client to specify which states can be accessed using `addTransition`. If I had access to the state I want to jump to from within the current state (without the need for iterating), I would be able to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface State<T extends Script> {

}
```

We can't be sure what `T` will be *until a subclass of `State` is instantiated*. We know it will be a subtype of `Script`, but we can't be sure which one.

Since we don't instantiate any of the states within the `TransitionTable`, we don't know which `Script` subtype is being used for the states being passed into `TransitionTable`. Since we aren't sure which subtype is being used for the state, we can't be sure that `<T extends Script>` will be the correct subtype.

To fix this, I made `TransitionTable` accept a generic type argument; the type of the state. I changed `StateNode` from a static nested class to a regular nested class, so it inherits the generic type:

```
public class TransitionTable<T extends Script<?>> {
    private Map<T, StateNode> entries = new HashMap<>()
    private StateNode current, start;

    public T getCurrentState() {
        return current.state;
    }

    public StateNode createNode(T state) {
        StateNode entry = new StateNode(state);
        entries.put(state, entry);

        if (startNode == null) {
            startNode = currentNode = entry;
        }
        return entry;
    }

    public class StateNode {
        private ArrayList<T> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        private T state;

        private StateNode(T state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public StateNode addTransition(T state) {
            nodes.add(state);
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Then brought the processing up to where I declare all my types:

```
State<DemoScript> start = new StartState();
State<DemoScript> walkToA = new WalkToAState();
State<DemoScript> walkToB = new WalkToBState();
State<DemoScript> dance = new DanceState();

TransitionTable<State<DemoScript>> table = new TransitionTable();
table.createNode(start).addTransition(walkToA).addTransition(walkToB);
table.createNode(dance).addTransition(walkToA).addTransition(walkToB);
table.createNode(walkToA).addTransition(dance);
table.createNode(walkToB).addTransition(dance);

public void loop() {
    table.getCurrentState().process(this, table);
}
```

Don't make comments on how verbose it is; I shall be improving that in the future

Comment: This solution is definitely better than mine, mostly because I was working with a precondition which apparently does not exist: In your implementation, each instance of TransitionTable only supports 1 type of Script to be executed. I was under the impression multiple script types should be supported, but apparently, I misunderstood.

Comment: @DavidtenHove I can see how you would have assumed that; I should have specified that the type parameter for the method was a cheap hack to pass a `Script` type to that method. Although the method was able to accept different `Script` types using thay generic, it was gonna be the same type. That's what bad design gets you: misunderstandings. I will make sure to be more clear in the future; I'm sorry for the miscommunication

Comment: No problem. Clearing up misunderstandings is what this website is for :)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, somwewhere you will have to do the check if the script you are trying to process can be accepted by the current state, and I don't see an (easy) way of doing this compiletime. One way of doing it at runtime is storing a `Class<T>` reference in your state and call `Class.isAssignableFrom`.

Another method would be to let the calling code sort out the problem itself. You can do this by removing the `process` method from your `TransitionTable` and replacing it with something like this:

```
public <T extends Script> Processor<T> getProcessorForCurrentState() {
    //This cast can't go wrong because we haven't bound T yet
    State<T> current = (State<T>)currentNode.mainState;
    return new Processor<T>(current);
}

public static class Processor<T extends Script> {
    private State<T> state;
    private Processor(State<T> state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public void process(T script) {
        //TODO make sure this isn't called twice
        this.state.process(script);
    }
}
```

But again, this relays the runtime checking to the client code instead of in the table. It depends on your situation if this is preferable.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this solution is not satisfactory. I'm not looking for a run-time solution, nor am I a fan of down-casting unless absolutely requires. Once again, thanks for taking the time to write this, but I actually found a solution to my problem, which I'm going to post an answer about now

Comment: I have posted my answer, if you were interested