# Foo<?, ?, ?> isn't Foo<?, ?, ?>

Tags: generics, java-7, guava

I have a very simple method that I can't get to work:

```
private Map<UUID, Foo<?, ?, ?>> foos = new HashMap<UUID, Foo<?, ?, ?>>();

public Optional<Foo<?, ?, ?>> getFoo(UUID id){
    return Optional.fromNullable(foos.get(id)); //Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<Action<capture#31-of ?,capture#32-of ?,capture#33-of ?>> to Optional<Action<?,?,?>>
}
```

How could these be incompatible types? How can I work around this?

Comment: The problem is, the types that are infered when you call the method might not match the types that your map support. For example, your map could have `Foo<String, Integer, Object>`, yet the method call might infer it's generic type as `Foo<List, String, int[]>` (something different).  You have 2 different generic declarations. I had this sinilar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699756/cant-use-generic-type-declared-at-method-level-for-method-argument-that-require)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code compiles in Java 8.  (The [`Optional.fromNullable` method is from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html#fromNullable(T))).

But it doesn't compile in Java 7, where I get your compiler error.

[Java 8 has improved "target type" type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html).

> Improved Type Inference - The Java compiler takes advantage of target typing to infer the type parameters of a generic method invocation. The target type of an expression is the data type that the Java compiler expects depending on where the expression appears. For example, you can use an assignment statement's target type for type inference in Java SE 7. However, in Java SE 8, you can use the target type for type inference in more contexts.

To make this compile in Java 7, you can insert a type argument to the `fromNullable` method.

```
return Optional.<Foo<?, ?, ?>>fromNullable(foos.get(id));
```

This is not necessary in Java 8, which can compile it without the type argument.

(If you have Java 8 but you don't have Guava, you can use Java 8's `Optional.ofNullable` method).

Answer (score 0):

Might be the type inference getting confused. Try

```
Optional.<Foo<?, ?, ?>>fromNullable(foos.get(id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use `Optional<? extends Foo<?, ?, ?>>`.  Different ?'s having different meanings gets weird, but that approach often works.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcards objects (in Java 7 at least) can't be modified, you only can extract data from it.

For example, you can:

```
 public void example( List<?> myList1, List<?> myList2 ){
    myList1.get(0); //this works
    myList1.add( myList2.get(0) );
 }
```

So, could the method you call been modifying the object internally?